# Proof of integrability of function through step functions

Tags: integration, proof-writing, step-function

Prove that function $f(x)$ is integrable if and only if for all $ε > 0$, there exist step functions $s, t$ (defined on the same bounds as $f$) such that $s ≤ f ≤ t$ and $$∫(t-s)(x)dx < ε. \quad \square$$

Comment: What is the integral you are using?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: the integral is from an arbitrary [a, b] such that f, s, and t are all bounded and defined on [a, b]

Answer (score 0):

Let $[a,b]$ be the bounded intervall on which $f$ is defined and bounded and $\mathcal E$ the set of step functions on $[a,b]$.

$\Longrightarrow$ : Assume $f$ is Riemann integrable, we have
$$
I(f)_-:= \sup_{\phi \in \mathcal E, \phi \leq f} I(\phi) = \inf_{\psi \in \mathcal E,\psi \geq f} I(\psi) =: I(f)_+
$$
the common value being a real number. Then by definition of the sup/inf, forall $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\phi,\psi \in \mathcal E$ such that $\phi \leq f \leq \psi$ and
$$I(\psi) - \epsilon < I(f)_+ = I(f)_-< I(\phi) + \epsilon.$$
Then by linearity you get
$$
I(\psi-\phi) = I(\psi)-I(\phi) < 2 \epsilon.
$$
$\Longleftarrow$ : Assume that forall $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\phi,\psi \in \mathcal E$ such that $\phi \leq f \leq \psi$ and $I(\psi - \phi) < \epsilon$. We show that $I(f)_+ = I(f)_-$. We have one inequality for free thanks to the monotony of the Riemann integral over simple functions : forall $\phi,\psi \in \mathcal E$ such that $\phi \leq f \leq \psi$ we have
$$
I(\phi) \leq I(\psi)
$$
so
$$
I(f)_ -\leq I(f)_+.
$$
For the other inequality, notice that by assumption you have that forall $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\phi,\psi \in \mathcal E$ such that $\phi \leq f \leq \psi$ and $I(\psi - \phi) < \epsilon$, so
$$
I(f)_+ \leq I(\psi) < I(\phi) + \epsilon \leq I(f)_- + \epsilon
$$
and taking $\epsilon$ to 0 you are done.